# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() Python Error

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to figure out why this error keeps happening with my specific code as i'm trying to get better with numpy and mathematics within python. I keep getting this as a error and i can't seem to figure out a fix to it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vejh.png)

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Did you try copying and pasting that error message (or any part thereof) into a search engine? Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ ; please [do not post your code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551); and please [try to do your own research first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and [at least post complete error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146).

Comment: Also: **why are you using Numpy for this code**? You are aware that the standard library can provide random numbers, yes?

Answer (score 1):

You should not write `if a == b:` to compare two numpy arrays.  The value of `a == b` is a boolean array comparing the corresponding elements of `a` and `b`.  The error message is telling you that you should be writing `np.all(a == b)`.

Numpy gives you this error message any time it sees the user trying to take the boolean value of an array.